# Suggesting the next available IP network block

Tags: python

I was wondering if there's a good way to find the next available gap to create a network block given a list of existing ones?

For example, I have these networks in my list:

```
[
    '10.0.0.0/24',
    '10.0.0.0/20',
    '10.10.0.0/20',
]
```

and then someone comes along and ask: "Do you have have enough space for 1 /22 for me?"

I'd like to be able to suggest something along the line:
"Here's a space: x.x.x.x/22" (x.x.x.x is something that comes before 10.0.0.0)

or

"Here's a space: x.x.x.x/22" (x.x.x.x is something in between 10.0.0.255 and 10.10.0.0)

or

"Here's a space: x.x.x.x/22" (x.x.x.x is something that comes after 10.10.15.255)

I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) library is good for this sort of use case. You can use the `IPv4Network` class to define subnet ranges, and the `IPv4Address` objects it can return can be converted into integers for comparison.

What I do below:

1. Establish your given list as a list of `IPv4Network`s
2. Determine the size of the block we're looking for
3. Iterate through the list, computing the amount of space between consecutive blocks, and checking if our wanted block fits.

You could also return an `IPv4Network` with the subnet built into it, instead of an `IPv4Address`, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Network, IPv4Address

networks = [
    IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/24')
    IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/20')
    IPv4Network('10.0.10.0/20')
]

wanted = 22
wanted_size = 2 ** (32 - wanted)  # number of addresses in a /22

space_found = None
for i in range(1, len(networks):
    previous_network_end = int(networks[i-1].network_address + int(networks[i-1].hostmask))
    next_network_start   = int(networks[i].network_address)
    free_space_size      = next_network_start - previous_network_end
    if free_space_size >= wanted_size:
        return IPv4Address(networks[i-1] + 1)  # first available address
```

Comment: This is really spot on. May I add sorting and trimming the list of subnets from the list before looping would be a good idea. Much appreciated, Green Cloak Guy.

Comment: 1 more quick comment (not asking you to solve it) : If I have this list `[IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/8'), IPv4Network('100.0.0.0/26'), IPv4Network('191.0.0.0/8'), IPv4Network('191.1.0.0/24'), IPv4Network('192.0.0.0/24')]` and Im looking for /22 spaces, I'd get 11.0.0.0, 100.0.0.64, 191.1.1.0 as next available gap start addresses. But 100.0.0.64 and 191.1.1.0 can't be network address for a /22, therefore, you still have to work to find out if we can allocate a /22 with those gaps. but that's another fun problem to solve. ta

Comment: Yeah, for that you would need to put in additional checks and "accelerate" to the next possible `/22` start point. Should still be doable - would be one function call when you're defining `previous_network_end` which you'd have to write